# Change css to extend the content

Tags: html, css

Int he following css how to make the div wrapper to occupy the full screen and not only in the center

```
body {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   background:#71726e;
   }
div, p, span, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, form {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   }

.wrapper {
   margin:0px auto;
   padding:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:951px;
   background:url(../images/mid-shadow.jpg) repeat left top;
   }
 left-gap1 {
   margin:    0px ;
   padding:0px;
   font-size:0px;
   line-height:0px;
   width:6px;
   float:left;
   }
.right-gap1 {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   font-size:0px;
   line-height:0px;
   width:6px;
   float:left;
   }
.main {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:939px;
   float:left;
   }
.header {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:939px;
   float:left;    
   }
.nav-area {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:939px;
   height:54px;
   float:left;
   background:#000000;
   }
```

Comment: If you need a wrapper to occupy the full screen why not just use the body?

Comment: did you manage to figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the wrapper width to 100%

```
.wrapper {
   margin:0px auto; /* I guess you wont need this here */
   padding:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:100%;   /* Change This */
   background:url(../images/mid-shadow.jpg) repeat left top;
   }
```

Note : This will just use 100% width of your screen and not the height, if you are using image as a background in your website than I will recommend you to use background-image property on your `<body>` tag.

Edit as per your new requirement

You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jxFQx/)?

Comment: It kind of brings a gap on the Right side of the UI with margin

Comment: Or can u guide me to a professional html template with left navigation bar and right panel to be be 100% width

Comment: Yes i want something like that but more professional.I can give my html .I am not good at css

Comment: haha but you need to style it bro, am just here to solve your doubts and not to style your template

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
   padding:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 100%;
   background:url(../images/mid-shadow.jpg) repeat left top;
   }
```

Using margin: 0px auto; along with width: 951px; will center your content and only give it 951px in width. The content will not go wider than that. Set it to 100% as shown above.

Comment: It kind of brings a gap on the Right side of theUI with margin

Comment: If you want your content to span the entire page, you need to remove the widths that you have set in other plaecs like .main, .header and .navarea. They will be restricting the width.